# openlayers layers with arrow

Tags: caching, extjs, openlayers

I am using for my gis project openlayers and extjs ..
last day i saw an app which has a arrow ... and when you move your mouse satellite layer slide on raster layer...

i  am using arcgiscache.

with javascript can we do this?

Comment: Do you mean an arrow that points at north?

Comment: I suggest you interact more with the people answering your questions - comment them or mark as answers. Otherwise people won't feel like answering your questions in the future. Just a tip.

Comment: Hello? Are you interested in getting any more response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/bjornharrtell/swipe/examples/swipe.html) example using the Swipe class, maybe that could be of some help?

The Swipe class doesn't seem to be in the default OpenLayers download, the example uses [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/bjornharrtell/swipe/lib/OpenLayers/Control/Swipe.js) file, download that and reference in your app and you should be able to use it according to the example.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for:
http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/layeropacityslider.html

Comment: i am sorry but it is not my request, i know changing the opacity of layer . i want to add OpenLayers.Control.Swipe ... but it gives "is not a constructor"

Comment: If you want help with the "Swipe" error, I suggest you start a new thread. Much easier to help with clear questions.